# Как выбрать элемент по тексту?

Tags: css

Внутри `div` есть `label` с текстом. Надо выбрать этот `div`. Для этого надо сначала выбрать `label`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. консорциум не хочет связываться с ["числом зверя"](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors), то только через JS:

```js
// Если без украшательств, то должно выглядеть так:
function fGetParentForLabel(sTxt) {
  // С помощью XPath, находим в документе тег <label> содержащий заданный текст
  let result = document.evaluate('//label[contains(., "' + sTxt + '")]', document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  // Если такой элемент найден, тогда...
  if (result.snapshotLength) {
    // Собственно, получаем нужный parent-элемент с помощью 'closest()'
    // (если найдено несколько совпадений, то берём только первое (0-based))
    return result.snapshotItem(0).closest('.label-list');
  }
}

// Пример работы XPath
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('.input-text').addEventListener('input', function() {
    let result = document.evaluate('//label[contains(., "")]', document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (let i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
      result.snapshotItem(i).style.background = '';
    }
    if (this.value) {
      // С помощью XPath, находим все <label> содержащие заданный текст
      let result = document.evaluate('//label[contains(., "' + this.value + '")]', document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
      // Если такие элементы найдены, тогда...
      if (result.snapshotLength) {
        // Перебираем найденное
        for (let i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
          // Подсвечиваем нужный <label>
          result.snapshotItem(i).style.background = '#f99';
        }
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(fGetParentForLabel('оже la'));
}
```

```css
.input-text {
  width: 300px;
}

.label-list {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input class="input-text" placeholder="Введите текст содержащийся в искомом <label>"><br>
<br>
<div class="label-list">
  <label>Это первый label</label><br>
  <label>Вот второй label</label><br>
  <label>Это средний label</label><br>
  <label>Это тоже label</label><br>
  <label>А это сааамый последний label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: А что значит связываться с "числом зверя"?

Comment: @Andru по ссылке ходили? Номер пункта видели? Вот, то-то и [оно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F) ...