# Заполучить элемент по тексту потомков

Tags: xpath

Как именно по тексту всех потомков, получить элемент ?

Так я получаю только родителя необходимого элемента:

```
//*[node()='текст всех потомков']
```

**Дополнительный вопрос:** возможно ли найти элемент по его innerHTML и outerHTML ?

Comment: Возможно, поможет - [Как выбрать элемент по тексту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879574/265406)

Comment: @UModeL Да нет, это не то, там изначально знают какой текст в каком потомке.  Я же, имею только текст неизвестных мне потомков.

Comment: Можно увидеть пример DOM'а и элементы в нём, которые надо найти и которыми можно оперировать в поиске?

Comment: @Vipz главное, что у Вас есть текст. (см. ответ).

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oInput = document.querySelector('.input');
  oInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    // "Известный текст"
    var sSearch = 'Inner';
    // С помощью XPath, находим элементы содержащие "известный текст"
    var result = document.evaluate('//*[contains(., "' + oInput.value + '")]', document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    // Если такие элементы найдены, тогда...
    if (result.snapshotLength) {
      // Получаем родителя и выводим его имя тега
      console.log(result.snapshotItem(result.snapshotLength - 1).tagName);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="input">
  <p>TextBlock <span>TextPart</span></p>
  <h4>TextHead <i>Oblique <strong>Bold</strong></i></h4>
  Inner
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сохраню, но пока хватает этого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312495